# SQL query that changes if date is today

Tags: mysql

I'm having trouble deciding how to grab the latest episode ID from a mysql database.

What I need is to grab the most recent `air_date` that is in the past, but if the episode is airing today, the return this one.  The code I have isn't working and I think I'm missing something.  IF anyone has any suggestions how to achieve this,  I would appreciate it:

```
$today = mktime(0, 0, 0);

"SELECT `id` FROM `hm_episodes_main`
WHERE `show_id` = '{$iShowId}'
AND `episode_voting` = 'Yes'
AND `air_date` < '{$today}'
ORDER BY `air_date` DESC"
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but it sounds like you just need the most recent air date.  Because if the episode is airing today, then that's the most recent.  Is the problem that if it's airing today, then that date doesn't count as an `air_date`?

Comment: The most recent air date in the past.  But if the air date is 7PM and it's 11AM it wont' be in the past yet, but In thinking about it, I might have just answered my question.  I'll just do a check to see if there's an episode today, then if not continue with one in the past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may just need to modify your existing query to include the current date:

AND `air_date` **<=** '{$today}'

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, `air_date` is an epoch timestamp.  How about:

```
   SELECT `id`
     FROM `hm_episodes_main`
    WHERE `show_id` = ?                  -- plug $iShowId in here
          AND
          `episode_voting` = 'YES'
          AND
          `air_date` <= UNIX_TIMESTAMP() -- no need for mktime()
 ORDER BY `air_date` DESC
    LIMIT 1;
```